# What is the method for the NSSearchField TextDidChange?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

What is the analogous method for the function `searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)` in macOS?

Got the answer:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: NSSearchField!
  func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification){
    let searchObject:NSSearchField? = obj.object as? NSSearchField
    if searchObject==self.searchBar{

    }
}
```

Comment: Please delete your "got the answer" edit and repost that as an actual Answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent is the delegate method [controlTextDidChange:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontroltexteditingdelegate/3005177-controltextdidchange)

The object of the `notification` is the `NSSearchfield`. You have to cast the type

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: NSSearchField!

func controlTextDidChange(_ notification : Notification){
    guard let field = notification.object as? NSSearchField, field == self.searchBar else { return }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `controlTextDidChange` method as shown in the pic below(last method) then the `searchFieldDidEndSearching`

keeps track of when you finish searching or if searchbar is empty and the `searchFieldDidStartSearching(_ sender: NSSearchField)` gets called when you just start editing the textfield after being empty

```
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.searchTable.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func searchFieldDidStartSearching(_ sender: NSSearchField) {


    }

    func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
        guard let field = obj.object as? NSSearchField, field == self.searchBar else { return }
        filteredPokemonList = allPokemonList.filter({ (pokemon) -> Bool in
            return pokemon.name.lowercased().contains(field.stringValue.lowercased())
        })

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.searchTable.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

below is a pic of my ***Attribute Inspector*** to have a function called based on each letter entered to filter and reload the NSTableView

[image]